# Is it possible to process a silent notification in iOS when your app is not running?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I haven't found the exact answer to this elsewhere on this site.  The goal is to send a silent remote notification (no user alert/badge/sound) to my app, with a custom payload, and then have the app process this even if it was not running when the notification was received.  If the app was not running, is it notified and given a chance to process the (silent) notification?  Or is it only notified the next time the app is launched?

So far, I've only been able to confirm that you can receive a non-silent notification when the app is not running, or a silent notification when the app IS running. I haven't seen confirmation of what happens if you receive a silent notification and are not running.

Comment: as far as I understand push notifications, the payload is NEVER be processed when the app is not running! Only when you open the app the next time `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` gets called!

Comment: of course it's `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` which gets called when the app launches.

Comment: Obviously the payload is not processed when the app is not running, but I think you are saying that the app is never launched automatically due to a notification -- it is either already running, or it is launched in response to the user selecting "View" or similar in a displayed UI alert.  Correct?   If that is correct, then is there no way to do what I am describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the answer that I've been able to find so far (and @Sebrassi concurs with above) is that what I am asking for is not possible.  The app does not get any processing time when a notification comes in, period, unless it is already running or the user launches it via the UI in one way or another.

Comment: I believe you're correct, with the exception of specialized APIs such as that for Newsstand or VOIP.